# how can I get a bigquery table schema in java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

lets say I have this `myTable` table in BQ:

```
[
  {"name": "executionId", "type": "STRING"},
  {"name":"metadata", "type":"record","fields":[
    {"name":"fileName", "type":"STRING"},
    {"name":"fileType", "type":"STRING"},
    {"name":"errors", "type":"STRING"}
  ]}
]
```

now I'm trying to get the tables schema in my  code. 
here is what I tried using this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java):

```
import com.google.cloud.examples.bigquery.snippets.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        BigQuerySnippets bigQuerySnippets = new BigQuerySnippets(bigquery);
        Table table = bigQuerySnippets.getTable("MY_DATASET", "myTable");
```

now how do I continue? 
does `table` have a method for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Table](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Table.html) extends [TableInfo](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TableInfo.html), so you can get the [TableDefinition](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html) from the TableInfo, and the [Schema](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/Schema.html) from the TableDefinition:

```
Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();
```

Comment: my code fails on the first line: 
`BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();`
I get this error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.getHttpTransportFactory()Lcom/google/cloud/HttpServiceOptions$HttpTransportFactory;`

Comment: Using this answer I was getting schema as `null`, but calling `table.reload()` first fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @MingweiSamuel that actually helped a lot