# Dataflow BigQuery read does not return correct datatype

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In Apache Beam/Dataflow I am reading data into a collection using the following code:

```
  // read the BigQuery data
PCollection<TableRow> bigQuerySource = p
    .apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(bigQueryQuery).usingStandardSql().withTemplateCompatibility());
```

The query is `"Select * from .."` querying a view that queries other views and tables.

In the next transformation I use the following:

```
..
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = c.element().entrySet();
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : entries) {
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    String x = value.getClass().getName();
  }
..
```

The view contains multiple datatypes, String/Date/Integer/Boolean, but the returning datatype in x is only String/Boolean.

How can I get the original datatype from the BigQuery Schema?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an instance of `com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery` then you can get the types of your columns. For instance, to get the first column's type:

```
BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(projectId)
                .setCredentials(...)
                .build()
                .getService();

bigQuery.getTable(id).getDefinition().getSchema().getFields().get(0).getType()
```

This will give you `LegacySQLTypeName`. According to source code, this is what you can expect:

```
 /** Variable-length binary data. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName BYTES = type.createAndRegister("BYTES").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.BYTES);
  /** Variable-length character (Unicode) data. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName STRING = type.createAndRegister("STRING").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.STRING);
  /** A 64-bit signed integer value. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName INTEGER = type.createAndRegister("INTEGER").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.INT64);
  /** A 64-bit IEEE binary floating-point value. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName FLOAT = type.createAndRegister("FLOAT").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.FLOAT64);
  /** A Boolean value (true or false). */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName BOOLEAN = type.createAndRegister("BOOLEAN").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.BOOL);
  /** Represents an absolute point in time, with microsecond precision. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName TIMESTAMP = type.createAndRegister("TIMESTAMP").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP);
  /** Represents a logical calendar date. Note, support for this type is limited in legacy SQL. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName DATE = type.createAndRegister("DATE").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.DATE);
  /**
   * Represents a time, independent of a specific date, to microsecond precision. Note, support for
   * this type is limited in legacy SQL.
   */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName TIME = type.createAndRegister("TIME").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.TIME);
  /**
   * Represents a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and subsecond (microsecond precision).
   * Note, support for this type is limited in legacy SQL.
   */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName DATETIME = type.createAndRegister("DATETIME").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.DATETIME);
  /** A record type with a nested schema. */
  public static final LegacySQLTypeName RECORD = type.createAndRegister("RECORD").setStandardType(StandardSQLTypeName.STRUCT);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. The pipeline is running as a template and that limits my options. I am looking for an option within the context of the TableRow. At this moment all fields are mentioned as unknown fields in the object. That does suggest there are known fields. Not sure what I am missing here, but the TableRow not knowing what datatype it contains does sound strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a similar issue here [how can I get a bigquery table schema in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261880/how-can-i-get-a-bigquery-table-schema-in-java) where the schema was returning null and they fixed it by calling the table.reload() first.

Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();

Also, you may check the corresponding class implementation and methods here: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html